# Lower case letters to upper case (if condition usage)?

Tags: c

What does this line mean?

```
if (strcmp(argv[0],"./lower")==0)
```

Before converting to lower or upper case why this condition is checked?
What does it results to?

Comment: Firstly, pick one language only. Then, what have you tried? What have you found out? Remember, nobody is going to do your homework for you here!

Comment: "What?" There is *no* "converting to lower or upper case" involved - the `strcmp` documentation quite clearly explain how it works (and see `stricmp` for comparison). Also, the question is better tagged as *only* C..

Comment: This code compiles in both c and c++, so the op tags are fine

Comment: did you read any C book, and did you read the manual for `strcmp`?

Comment: Just don't downvote it yet. it might be an application of soft links in ( as in Linux) where two softlinks to the same executable could be used to achieve different objectives based on the exe names. But as rightly observed  the doesn't do actual conversion, the subsequent code does which the op hasn't put in question

Comment: @CIsForCookies The "compiles in" argument is not sufficient enough to justify C *and* C++. The OP would have to be using C++ features, targeting a C++ compilation target, or asking about a C/C++ difference to justify the inclusion of a C++ as a tag (much less, both C *and* C++).. if any of these hold, it has not been demonstrated. (And using both language tags, for better or worse, tends to get more .. critical .. feedback on SO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have guessed, this doesn't do the actual conversion. But it in fact determines what conversion to do based on the executable name. Below is an example

Here is casefile_48248048.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
char str[30]="Some string";
short i=0;
printf("argv[0] = %s\n",argv[0]);
if(strcmp(argv[0],"./tolower")==0){
  printf("String in lower case : ");
  while(str[i])
   printf("%c",tolower(str[i++]));
  printf("\n");
}
else if(strcmp(argv[0],"./toupper")==0){
  printf("String in upper case : ");
  while(str[i])
   printf("%c",toupper(str[i++]));
  printf("\n");
}
else
  printf("No changes to be made to string");
return 0;
}
```

In linux, I compiled it using `gcc` like below

```
gcc  casefile_48248048.c -o  casefile_48248048
```

Then made two symbolic links to it

```
ln -s casefile_48248048 toupper
ln -s casefile_48248048 tolower
```

Then run `toupper` and `tolower` to give below results

```
$ ./toupper 
argv[0] = ./toupper
String in upper case : SOME STRING
$ ./tolower
argv[0] = ./tolower
String in lower case : some string
```

The point is clear, I hope :-)

Answer (score 2):

Comparing `argv[0]` is checking the name of the executable.

I assume you look at code similar to [busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) in which you check the executable that the user used so you know which action to perform.

Comment: argv [0] is the name **representing** the executable. It may be null, or may be some other name that represents it (i.e. you could pass a "nickname" in argv [0] instead of real executable name)